# How to make a smooth heatmap in plotly that includes null values

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

Given the following heatmap:

```js
var data = [
  {
    z: [[1, 20, null], [20, null, 60], [30, 60, 1]],
    type: 'heatmap',
    zsmooth: 'best',
    colorscale: 'Jet'
  }
];
Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

In this case I want the null values to show up as white, however it still should be "smooth".
The result displays a "smooth" heatmap, however the white null values show up as a square and isnt smoothed.

I am looking for a way to make the colored values rounded so it flows into the white section and looks less like a grid, almost like giving the cell a border-radius.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the smoothing algorithm to `zsmooth: 'fast'`, the color tone is quite different but the squares with NaN/null values will be smoothed properly eg. :

[image: heatmap img 1]

---

An other option is to set [`connectgaps`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Heatmap.html) to `true` so that missing values are ignored (no white squares) :

> **connectgaps** – Determines whether or not gaps (i.e. {nan} or missing
> values) in the z data are filled in.  It is defaulted to true if z is a one dimensional array and zsmooth is not false; otherwise it is defaulted to false.

eg. with 'best' smoothing algorithm :

[image: heatmap img 2]

Comment: This solved the problem thank you. I would ideally like the white space functionality to be the same "fast" while the rest of the plot looks like "best". Do you know if this is possible?

connectGaps doesnt work because I want to show the white space for nulls

Comment: Yes it would be nice to have this possibility but I don't think it's possible without rewriting a specific algorithm or tweaking the 'best' algorithm so that it can smooth NaN/null values properly.

Comment: Do you know if there are any resources available on if its possible to tweak the smoothing function in plotly or add a custom one?

Comment: No sorry I don't have any info about this.